# Can I reapply a refused Uk visa same week? How to address a statement on the refusal which was not true

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, visa-sponsors

I am a Ghanaian and I applied for a visitors visa to travel with my husband and stepchildren who already have UK Visas.
My uncle invited me. (initiation letter, payslip, bank statement and proof of address). My husband is the main sponsor (his payslip, bank statement, property documents and sales agreements) I added my bank statement, payslip, our joint statement and investment slip to show.

> You state you are applying for 15 days to visit your family. In support of your application you have provided your bank statement, employment letter, payslips and sponsor’s documents.
> I note the supporting evidence submitted in relation to your sponsor’s personal and financial circumstances. However, to consider whether or not you qualify, I must be satisfied of your own personal and financial circumstances, as portrayed in your application and supporting information.
>
> I acknowledge your declared employment and I note your employment letter and wage slips provided. However, when contrasting your personal bank statement with your provided payslips, I note that in July 2021 you are not in receipt of the figure given in your payslip for this month. The figure seen entering your account far exceeds the figure given in your payslip. This casts doubt as to whether these payslips provide a genuine reflection of your employment in your country of residence, and, in turn, casts doubt as to whether you are employed with this employer as stated.
>
> In light of the above, I also note that you are in receipt of regular large deposits that are not explained by the other supporting information you have provided. Multiple large and regular deposits are seen entering your account in addition to transactions that mirror the figures provided in your additional payslips. I note that you have not declared an additional income and that the source of these deposits are not explained by your supporting information. You are therefore in receipt of regular large funds that exceed your monthly wage for which the source of these are not explained by your supporting information. Given that the source of these funds are unexplained by your employment or other supporting information, I am not satisfied that you have given an accurate reflection of your circumstances and that these funds are genuinely available for your personal use.

Comment: Can I reapply since the statement is not true about my payslip and deposits

Comment: I have closed as duplicate - that other question discusses provenance of funds, which is the sticking point here.

Comment: When your husband and step-children applied for their visas, did they state that you intended to travel with them? Possession of a visa does *not* guarantee entry.

Comment: They already have visas before I applied.

Comment: Is it untrue that there are multiple large deposits into your account that don't match your payslips and are unexplained in the application?

Comment: So whats the “not true” part?

Comment: Patience, éti sein? Yes you can reapply immediately and explain the source of your additional large deposit funds. There’s a section that allows you to add additional information. The British sometimes exhibit foolish paranoia about source of funds and look for any excuse to refuse visas.

Comment: @Augustine of Hippo I guess the British foolish paranoia about source of funds stems from a concern to ascertain the legality of earnings and the veracity of the application. It’s usually necessary to play by the rules of the country you want to visit, anyone who dislikes having to do that is free to choose to apply elsewhere.

Comment: @Traveller That’s hypocritical and nonsense to me. Did they care about all the dirty billions that poured into London real estate from criminal Russian oligarchs? Yeah right! Give me a break!

Comment: I do not have any large funds in my account. Moreso the amount of my salary in july is correct. My salary for June delayed and was paid in July . I am sure the person checking the documents did not check it well.